# WCF enum not exposed

Tags: c#, wcf, enums

I have two `enum` in my WCF. One works and one doesn't and I cannot figure out why. The two are the following:

```
[DataContract(Name="RTMImageType")]
public enum RTMImageType
{
    [EnumMember]
    NOTDEFINED = 0,
    [EnumMember]
    VEHICLE = 1,
    [EnumMember]
    GENERAL = 2,
    [EnumMember]
    INVOICE = 3,
    [EnumMember]
    CUSTOM = 4
}

[DataContract(Name = "RTMStatusButtonColor")]
public enum RTMStatusButtonColor
{
    [EnumMember]
    RED = 0,
    [EnumMember]
    YELLOW = 1,
    [EnumMember]
    GREEN = 2
}
```

When I add a service reference to my client test class, `RTMStatusButtonColor` is exposed and works but `RTMImageType` is not and I cannot figure out why since they are both in the same namespace.

What would cause one `enum` to be exposed while the other in the same namespace stays hidden from the client?

Comment: Is your RTMImageType enum used in public contract of service?

Comment: I just noticed that it is not. When I did a test and added it to one of my contracts it was then exposed. How do I force it to be exposed to the client so the client can use it?

Comment: Why it should if your service don't want to get it in operations?